# How to start app from Android browser, when I type in "myapp://" in address bar

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-intent

I need the browser to start my app whenever I enter the "myapp://blah.com/a?b=1&c=2" in the browser. I have searched a lot on this topic, but non of the answers really helped me. Could you please help to understand what I'm missing?

```
<activity android:name=".MyAppMain"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myapp" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

After installation from Eclipse (Run As Android application) my app can work ok on its own, but when I type in "myapp://blah.com/a?b=1&c=2", the browser is simply googling for this string. Could you point out what else I'm missing? Do I need after installation to somehow register in the system that I want to handle "myapp://" urls?

Comment: Does it work if you only use that one `<intent-filter>` in your manifest?

Comment: No, Daniel, it's still googling :-)

Comment: @user789175 did you figure this out?

Comment: Launching apps via custom URL in Android browser has already been covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: possible duplicate of [Launch custom android application from android browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser)

Comment: Check out this answer for why it isn't working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463794/android-custom-uri-scheme-incorrectly-encoded-when-type-in-browser

Basically,

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using the

```
  <activity android:name=".ReceiveInviteActivity">

            <intent-filter >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                 <data
                 android:scheme="appname" 
                 android:host="project.example.com"

                />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

And activity

```
 if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
            final List<String> segments = intent.getData().getPathSegments();
            Log.d("LISTARRAY",segments.toString());
            String idString = segments.get(0);
            Log.d("LISTITEM",segments.get(0).getClass().toString());
            String friendId = idString.substring((idString.indexOf("="))+1);
            Log.d("friendId!",friendId);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer for why it isn't working: [Android custom URI scheme incorrectly encoded when type in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463794/android-custom-uri-scheme-incorrectly-encoded-when-type-in-browser)

Basically, the default Android browser only accepts certain URI schemes, so your custom one won't work when typed directly into the URL bar.